# Find the minimum possible number of elements greater than x that can be left after performing m operations of incrementing n elements

Tags: algorithm

Given the **x**, **n**, **m**, and the sorted array **a** (each element of a is not greater than x). One operation is incrementing n elements of **a** (adding 1 to each of chosen element). The question is, what is the minimum number of elements that are greater than **x** can be left after performing **m** operations?

Is it possible to find the answer without actually modifying the array / creating another array?
I tried to work out a formula: n - ((len(a) * x - sum(a)) / m), but it doesn't seem to be correct. If I were to solve this manually by hand, I would just use the sliding window from the back of the array, making all the elements equal to x, but I don't think I can afford doing this in program due to the time limits. So any piece of advice will be useful, thanks.

Comment: Assuming that you can chose any `n` elements (not just a contiguous subarray), then the correct answer is to find the `y` elements closest to `x`, and increment those elements in every operation. Where `y` is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @user3386109 but you need to increment exactly n elements each time. Plus, choosing only those elements that are the closest and incrementing them all the way m times isn't a good idea obviously.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you only increment `y` elements. Certainly you need to increment `n` elements in each operation. But the `y` elements that will be greater than `x` should be incremented all `m` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total amount of incrementing to be done is `n*m`.

The best way to arrange it to to divide the array `a` into three regions.

1. The area where `a[i] + m <= x`. They get incremented every time, and will absorb `m` of the increments.
2. The area where `x < a[i] + m` but we won't increment them past `x`. They can absorb `x - a[i]` of the increments.
3. The area where `x < a[i] + m` but we WILL increment them past `x`. They can be incremented every time and will absorb `m` of the increments. Which is `m - x + a[i]` more increments than when included in the second region.

If `a` has fewer than `n` elements, throw an exception. The problem is impossible. We can't find `n` elements in `a` for a single update.

So working from the smallest to the largest we figure out how many increments are absorbable by putting things into the first and second groups. If that is enough, the answer is 0.

If we need more incrementing, go through `a` from the largest to the smallest element. Keep adding `m - x + a[i]` until we've reached or exceeded `n * m` increments. The number that you put into group 3 is your answer.